# What is the complexity of SetLength?

Tags: dynamic-arrays, freepascal

I often need to call SetLength multiple times to increase some dynamic array's length. What is the complexity of the following code?

```
const 
  n = 1000000;
var
  a: array of integer;

for i := 1 to n do
  SetLength(a, i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SetLength complexity is O(1), your algorithm will have a O(n) complexity because you call SetLength n times.

Maybe this article could help you for further related questions : https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/computer-science/threads/13488/time-complexity-of-algorithm

Comment: I'm not sure that the complexity of SetLength is O(1). You are assuming what I am asking: "What is the complexity of SetLength".

Comment: Yes, I am assuming this.
Based on experience, I think SetLength complexity is between O(1) in the best case and O(n) in the worst case

You might want to try to benchmark it to verify assumptions

Answer (score 1):

A single SetLength call can have O(n) complexity, because if the memory after the end of the array is used for something else, the entire array has to be copied to a new position (i.e. it may have to make an entirely new array, copy the contents from the old one, free the old one).

This would suggest that the code you presented would have O(n^2) complexity. However if you benchmark it you'll most likely find that doubling n only doubles running time, suggesting that the entire algorithm runs in O(n) which in turn suggests that SetLength is O(1). What's most likely happening is that memory manager actually occupies more memory than you requested for the array. Therefore in subsequent SetLength calls it can easily increase the length of the array because memory after the end of the array is actually already reserved for the array.

However I would still not grow a dynamic array by one in each iteration. You'll still get much better performance (specially if you run millions of iterations), if you only do one SetLength call in advance. In your case I would do

```
SetLength(a, n);
for i := 1 to n do
  // no need for SetLength here
```

If you don't know how big the array has to be you can do something like that

```
SetLength(a, 16);
aLength := 0;
while Whatever do
begin
  if aLength = Length(a) then
    SetLength(a, aLength * 2);
  ...
  a[aLength] := ...
  Inc(aLength);
  ...
end;
```

Here I used 16 for the initial length of the array and double the length once the array becomes full. These can be adjusted depending on the problem at hand.

Also consider if you can use some available datastructure instead, with [TList](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tlist.html) for example you don't have to worry about growing the array yourself. I'm not sure if there's a generic version of TList available in FreePascal, but it would probably be the best option.